# Hiding a cardview using child webview in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently using android studio for a dashboard to visualize live data.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webviewCO2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CO2"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:textColor="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CO2_ti"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="40dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is one of the components of my dashboard. However, some of the devices do not have a CO2 sensor and I would like to completely hide this in the view when that is the case.
When I have the webview, is there some sort of code to get the "parent element" just like in html so that I can set the visibility of the CardView to GONE?
I am currently able to get the webview like this

```
WebView webViewCO2;
webViewCO2 = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webviewCO2);
```

Is there somthing similar I cuold  do to get the cardView such that I can change its visibility? (Maybe if I gave the cardView an id?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cv_id);
```

and

```
cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

did the trick